Proof that $n!\leq 2 \left(\frac{n}{2}\right)^n$
I am not sure about my proof and I would appreciate some help.
We have $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and don't include $0$.
Proof:
We will prove the equivalent statement $$ \frac{n!}{n^n} \leq \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}$$ by induction.
The base case n=1 is obvious.
Induction step:
$n\rightarrow n+1$
$$\frac{(n+1)!}{(n+1)^{n+1}}=\frac{n!}{(n+1)^n}\leq \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}\cdot \frac{n^n}{(n+1)^n}\leq \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{2^n}$$
Is my proof valid? I'm not sure about the induction step. I would like to finish this myself if something is wrong.

Sorry, we have $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and 0 is not included. My question is whether my induction step is valid or not. I think it is but I don't want to make a stupid mistake.

What exactly in the induction step is the "problem"? Which term? You should add then $n\ge 1$, because for many people $0\in \Bbb N$.

Yes it looks fine!

I have edited the question. It's only that I fear that there is something I have forgotten. I think my inequalities are valid. Are they?

Yes, this is fine. It suffices to show [in the last line of your proof] that the inequality $(n+1)^n \ge 2 n^n$ is true for $n \ge 2$. [one can check directly the cases $n=1$ and $n=2$ that indeed the inequality $\frac{n!} {n^n} \le \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}$ is true for those $n$ and so what remains is showing that this inequslity is true for integers $n \ge 3$].
But by the binomial theorem [and assuming $n$ is at least $2$]:
$$(n+1)^n = n^n + \sum_{i=1}^n {n \choose i} n^{n-i} $$
$$> n^n + {n \choose 1}n^{n-1} = n^n +n^n = 2 n^n.$$
So in particular, $$(n+1)^n > 2 n^n,$$ [thus strict inequality is also true for $n \ge 2$] which is what you want.

Thank you for your help!

Your answer seems fine.
You could clarify why $\frac{n^n}{(n+1)^n}\leq\frac12.$ Inverting, you get this would be equivalent to $(1+1/n)^n\geq 2,$ which follows by Bernoulli's inequality or by expanding with binomial theorem and realize the first two terms are $1+n\cdot \frac1n=2.$
You can use $AM/GM$ to avoid induction.
You get from AM/GM that $$\sqrt[n-1]{(n-1)!}\leq \frac{n}2,\tag1$$ then raise both to the $n-1$th power to get: $$(n-1)!\leq \left(\frac{n}2\right)^{n-1}$$
Then multiply both sides by $n=2\cdot\frac n2.$
Of course, {1) doesn't work for $n=0,$ since $(-1)!$ is undefined. It doesn't work for $n=1$ because $1=\sqrt[1]{0!}$ is not less than $1/2.$ But this proof works for $n>1,$ where $(n-1)!$ exists and defined as a non-empty product.

That's very cool. Thank you for your help!


Proof that $n!\leq 2 \left(\frac{n}{2}\right)^n$

Alternative approach:
The arithmetic mean of two (real) distinct positive numbers is always greater than the geometric mean.
In other words,  given two numbers $~(a + b)~$ and $~(a - b),~$ where $~a > b > 0,~$ the arithmetic mean is $~a,~$ and the geometric mean is $~\displaystyle \sqrt{a^2 - b^2} < \sqrt{a^2} = a.$
Without loss of generality, assume that $~n \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 3}}.$

$\underline{\text{Case 1:} ~n ~\text{is even}}$
Then
$$n = 2k \implies $$
$$n! = \left\{ ~\prod_{r=1}^{k-1} [ ~r \times (2k - r) ~] ~\right\} \times [ ~k \times 2k ~]. \tag1 $$
In (1) above, each pair of factors $~r~$ and $~(2k -r)~$ has an arithmetic mean of $~k~$ and so has a product that is less than $~k^2.~$
Therefore,
$$n! < (k^2)^{k-1} \times 2k^2 = 2k^{2k} = 2 ~\left( ~\frac{n}{2} ~\right)^n.$$

$\underline{\text{Case 2:} ~n ~\text{is odd}}$
Then
$$n = 2k+1 \implies $$
$$n! = \left\{ ~\prod_{r=1}^{k} [ ~r \times (2k + 1 - r) ~] ~\right\} \times [ ~(2k+1) ~]. \tag2 $$
In (2) above, each pair of factors $~r~$ and $~(2k +1 -r)~$ has an arithmetic mean of $~(k+1/2)~$ and so has a product that is less than $~(k + 1/2)^2.~$
Therefore,
$$n! < [ ~(k + 1/2)^2 ~]^{k} \times (2k+1) = \left[ ~\frac{n}{2} ~\right]^{2k} \times n$$
$$ = \left[ ~\frac{n}{2} ~\right]^{2k} \times 2 \frac{n}{2}$$
$$= 2 \times \left[ ~\frac{n}{2} ~\right]^{2k+1} = 2 \times \left[ ~\frac{n}{2} ~\right]^{n}.$$

Your proof is fine since, for the inductive step, using that $\frac{n!}{n^n} \leq \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}$, we have shown that $\frac{(n+1)!}{(n+1)^{n+1}}\leq \frac{1}{2^{n}}$.

As an alternative, to avoid induction, since $0<a\le 1 \iff 0<a^2\le 1$, we simply have
$$n!\leq 2 \left(\frac{n}{2}\right)^n\iff \prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{2k}{n}\le 1 \iff \prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{4k(n-k)}{n^2}\le 1$$
which is true since $\frac{4k(n-k)}{n^2}\le 1$ for any $k=1,\ldots,n-1$.

Well, the issue I  have with this answer is that it is not a priori clear that $n! \le \frac{n^{n+1}}{e^{n-1}}$ is true....or rather, the student would be required to prove this fact before he can use it....

Thank you for your help!

@Mike Yes of course! This is a bound we need to prove, I've linked a source for it. I agree that this is not so smart! I try to improve it. Thanks
